# What does '-' mean in python

Tags: python

I've seen the code for plotting in neural networks model training:

`plt.plot(epochs, acc, '-', color='orange', label='training acc')`

I am wondering what `'-'` does here?

Sometimes I see it being used in other libraries than `matplotlib`. Does it do different things in different scenarios in python? Thanks

Comment: Well, what does the `plot` documentation tell you?

Comment: `'-'` is a string with a single character.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga means more in this context

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, `'-'` is to make the line on your plot **solid**. For other styles, see the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html#matplotlib.pyplot.plot), but here's a snapshot:

```
Line Styles

'-'     solid line style
'--'    dashed line style
'-.'    dash-dot line style
':'     dotted line style
```

Comment: could you please consider the edited question? Thanks

Comment: can you be specific about which other plotting libraries you're referring to?